# How do you read the name of the ~/ operator in Dart

Tags: dart, operators, integer-division

Dart has an integer division operator that looks like this: `~/`

```dart
final x = 22 ~/ 7;    // 3
```

The docs show it [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#arithmetic-operators), but they don't say what it is called. Am I using the correct name to call it an "integer division operator"? I've seen other people write it as the `~/` operator ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716978/integer-division-in-dart-type-double-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-int) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101836/what-does-mean-in-dart)) but I don't know how to read that out loud. And how do you say `22 ~/ 7`?

Answer (score 4):

The name of the *operator* is `~/`. It's a general operator that any class can implement. You could call it the "tilde slash operator" if you need to pronounce it.

The operation that `~/` performs on `num`/`int`/`double` is generally called "integer division" or "truncating division".

Other classes could implement a `~/` operator too, and what it would be called there would depend on what it does. If any existed.
(`BigInt` does integer division as well, and I'm not aware of any other implementation of `~/` in common use).

There are a number of multi-symbol operators: `~/`, `>>`, `<<`, `[]`, `[]=`. People do usually name them after the most common use: Shift operators, index/index-set operators, so it would not be inconsistent to use "integer division operator" about `~/` as a default, but it is potentially misleading.
(Say, if someone inspired by C++ made `streamController << x` be equivalent to `streamController.add(x)`, then reading it as "streamController left-shift x` would probably be confusing.)

Comment: So if you were making a text to speech engine for visually impaired people, what should it say when it gets to `~/`? (For example, say it is reading your answer here.)

Comment: I'd probably go with "tilde slash operator". 
The `+` operator has the advantage of being a single existing mathematical operator, so it's named "plus" even when it's not used for adding. 
The `~/` is not a single operator, so reading it would be "tilde slash". It has no official existing name because it's not in common use. That said, people do call `>>` and `<<` shift operators, even though they are not necessarily used for shifts, so you can say "integer division operator" and probably not be misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

Your usage as **integer division** seems proper way as it conveys the meaning clearly.
Also `22~/7` can be said as *Integer division of 22 by 7*

Answer (score 2):

### Truncating division operator

`~/` is officially called the *truncating division operator* in the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html) for numbers, which I discovered by browsing the `num` source code:

```dart
  /**
   * Truncating division operator.
   *
   * If either operand is a [double] then the result of the truncating division
   * `a ~/ b` is equivalent to `(a / b).truncate().toInt()`.
   *
   * If both operands are [int]s then `a ~/ b` performs the truncating
   * integer division.
   */
  int operator ~/(num other);
```

### Notes

- Going off of @dev-aentgs's answer, I would read `22 ~/ 7` as "truncated division of 22 by 7" or maybe "22 divided by 7 then truncated."
- I take @Irn's point that the "tilde slash operator" could be put to a different use, but since truncating or integer division is the only listed use in the Dart documentation (correct me if I'm wrong), I'm going to call it the *truncating division operator* until I have a reason not to.